# Extracting a Title from a WYSIWYG TEXT Editor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I have a WYSIWYG TEXT EDITOR contained in ID = 'bunchofstuff', which contains text with a bunch of HTML (all types of tags).

Example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean consectetuer. Etiam venenatis.

Using JQUERY,

- Part 1 - How can I get the text in the ID bunchofstuff, strip out all the HTML so I just have TEXT
- Part 2 - If it's over 40 characters of text, display the 40 characters with a ... at the end
- Part 3 - If it's under 40 characters, just show the line of text w/o ... trailing at the end.

Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: We'd need to know what editor this is to know the correct API to use. Have you yet checked the editor's documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = $('bunchofstuff').text();
if (text.length) > 40) {
  text = text.substring(0, 37) + '...';
}
alert(text);
```

Comment: This doesn't strip out the HTML tags

Comment: It depends if bunchofstuff refers to the textarea or the WYSIWYG div.